# No of Nodes in which nodes are smaller and greater than the certain node

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree, graph-algorithm

Given a tree, count for each vertex number of nodes which are greater and number of nodes which are smaller than the vertex in its subtree.

I can find the answer for a single vertex by doing a depth-first search (DFS) but doing it for every vertex will definitely take a lot of time.

Can we get a faster solution for the problem?

Comment: A naive approach: Perform a DFS and keep a list of 'currently processed vertices' as a stack. When first visiting a node, add it to the stack, after the last visit remove it. The operations are sound given the traversal order in a DFS. The stack elements are tuples `(value, count)` being initialised with `(value, 0)`. Upon the first visit of each vertex, iterate through the stack and increment the counts appropriately. Upon removal of  stack element, store its `count` with the current node. This runs in `O(n^2)` ( `O(d*n)` with `d` the depth of the tree ).

Comment: Well I need a more optimised solution and this solution is quite intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

**A little more efficient approach:**

A more efficient approach is to do post order and using a Binary Search Tree type map ( probably in c++ the sorted map implementation should already use some sort of red black tree ) to store keys and their count.

Do a post order traversal of the tree. 
At each node after the traversal:

a) for greater nodes :

get the next highest value to the current node in the BST type map ( this should be done in `O( log n )` and count all values below it. ( this will save lot of time especially if tree is balanced ) but will be expensive if the tree is imbalanced.

b) for lesser nodes:

get the next smallest value to the current node in the BST type map ( this should be done in `O( log n )` and count all values above it.

```
//map - sorted map with keys and their count
//greater_map - unordered map that contains node as key and count of nodes greater than key node.
//lesser_map - unordered map that contains node as key and count of nodes lesser than key node.

post_order( Node root ) 
   if ( root == null ) return;

   for each child in root.children:
       post_order( child )

   int next_higher_key = find_next_higher_key( map, root_key )
   greater_map.insert(root, count_all_values_greater_than_equal_to(next_higher_key, map) )

   int next_smaller_key = find_next_smaller_key( map, root_key )
   lesser_map.insert(root, count_all_values_lesser_than_equal_to(next_smaller_key, map) )

   if ( !map[root_key] )
      map.insert( root_key, 1 )
   else
      map.insert( root_key, map[root_key] + 1 )
```

**Less efficient approach:**

Do a depth first search traversal of the tree once. At each node after you are done with the traversal, store the number of greater nodes and lesser nodes in two maps. Key will be the node at which you just finished your traversal and value will be number of nodes greater than the current node and number of nodes lesser than the current node respectively. From the map you could easily get number of nodes which are greater or smaller for any given node.

Pseudo code:

```
list_of_nodes dfs( Node root ) {
   list_of_nodes thisList = new list_of_nodes;
   if ( root == null ) return thisList;
   thisList.push( root );

   for each child in root.children:
       list_of_nodes childList = dfs( child )
       thisList.addAll( childList )

   int greater = 0, lesser = 0
   for each node in thisList:
       if node_value > root_value
           greater++
       else if node_value < root_value
           lesser++

   greatermap.insert( root, greater )
   lessermap.insert( root, lesser )

   return thisList
```

To get the number of greater, lesser nodes for any given node, you can just access the map.

```
dfs( root_of_tree );
greater_num = greatermap[node]
lesser_num = lessermap[node]
```

Comment: `for each child in root.children:
       list_of_nodes childList = dfs( child )
       thisList.addAll( childList )`  Here you are adding the list of subtree to the list of root which can result in quadratic complexity. @SomeDude

Comment: @AlexxVladisov Yes it will add to complexity. A more efficient approach is to use a sorted map to store keys and do a post order. Added to my answer.